# Dynamic Sheets calendar is calculating EOMONTH inconsistently and comparing formulas from two cells with same number giving FALSE result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get a cell to NOT calculate its current formula for day of the month. I have an idea involving =IF(F20<F1,F20+1,""). I'm not sure if that will solve my "overflow" issue on the calendar because whenever I try to compare a cell in the calendar with the cell I calculate end of month I keep getting an error. Now, I figure it has to do with the formatting but I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

I've tried changing the formatting to date [just show day] but that messed up the calendar. Then I tried using a helper column to convert external values into something the calendar can understand but I'm stuck. Literally have gone over the same values under different formats and nothing new is happening. I need a pair of fresh eyes on this.

Additionally, cell C8 is a weird function I copied from the original calendar. I know it's meant to offset the calendar if I wanted the calendar to show Saturday as it's initial date but can't figure out how it expressing the data since that is what I'm not able to add correctly. Also, in the top middle of the sheet I'm showing different values I used to calculate end of month and how I'm getting incorrect numbers, another issue I can't figure out.

Thank you in advance for the help! The link takes you to the spreadsheet, it's a copy meant for y'all to just add comments/functions. Hopefully that makes it easier to provide feedback.

[CLICK HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16n1Ca2G8yE5L17Et2cF_NOG0yOL0utvdo4dSsgplWGY/edit#gid=2105530815&range=B1) to see the sheet I'm working with.

Comment: EOMONTH already outputs a day. by wrapping it into DAY you actually convert it into date so 31 for august 2021 becomes datevalue 31 which is 29. Jan 1900

Answer (score 0):

change B2 to:

```
=EOMONTH(B1, 0)
```

and then E16 can be:

```
=IF(D16>$B$2-1, 1, D16+1)
```

and drag right...

[image]